# Is there a way to generate DAOs with JOOQ with findById returning Optional

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jooq

Using generated DAOs leads to copy-paste code like:

```java
var entity = dao.findById(id); 
log.debug("entity: {}", entity) 
if (entity == null){
    raise SpecificRuntimeException(); 
}
```

I will be very happy do it like this:

```java
var entity = dao.findOptionalById(id)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new SpecificRuntimeException())
```

Comment: I just think it's less error-prone

Answer (score 0):

That's not a conscious omission, just a missing feature, which will be added in jOOQ 3.16: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12583

As a workaround, you can generate that method on each of your generated `DAO` types yourself, as documented here: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-custom-code/